Function base on filter from separate table
I have two tables in Power BI connected by Plant between each other.
Plant



Plant
Catalogue




Plant A
A


Plant B
B



Material



Plant
Material




Plant A
Mat A


Plant B
Mat B






Sth 1
Sth 2




12
2


23
3



I want to create measure base on IF and "Catalogue" meaning IF(Catalogue=A, then STH 1 else STH2. Somehow I receive errors.
Not sure if it's important but data is filtered also by slicer (Plant).
I've tried two similar solutions, that ain't working
Actual price LC =   CALCULATE(IF( FILTER(Plant, Plant[Catalogue] ="A"), Material[STH 1],Material[STH 2])
Second option
Actual price LC =  VAR Price_catalogue = Plant[Catalogue] RETURN CALCULATE(IF( Price_Catalogue =  ="A"), Material[STH 1],Material[STH 2])
Unfortunately it still recognize Plant[Catalogue] as dataset not as single value.

Can you please provide an example of the output you expect? Also for the Material Table you have two tables in your question. Should that be one table with 4 columns?

Try this measure:
Actual price LC = 

VAR thisMat = MAXX(Plant, Plant[Catalogue])
VAR this1 = MAXX(Material, [Sth 1])
VAR this2 = MAXX(Material, [Sth 2])

RETURN IF(thisMat = "A", this1, this2)

Example Output of Measure:

